# Javascript is there a way to get the null or undefined in string format?

Tags: javascript

I can test null or undefined with ?? operator :

```
let test = undefined;
let result = test ?? "null or undefined"
```

But can I actually get "null" if it is null or "undefined" if it is undefined using ?? somehow ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just cast to string?

```js
const test = undefined;
const result = test ?? String(test);
console.log(result);
```